# Javascript image timout

Tags: javascript, image, timeout

Good day, i'm having a problem with my code, can't get to show the loading image for few seconds, while POST code is getting in database and gives backinformation to show.

```js
$("#poll_vote").click(function(){
var answer = $("input.panswer:checked").val();
var p_id = $("#p_id").val();

$("#poll_load").html("<tr><td align='center'><img src='/images/ajax/ajax4.gif'/></td></tr>");

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: "action=poll_vote&p_id="+p_id+"&answer="+answer+"&module="+module+"",
  dataType: 'html',
  url: "/ajax.php",
  success: function(data)
  {

    $("#poll_content").html(data);

  }
  });


});
```

I would hope on your fast help, i'm begginer in java, so can't dicide it myself.

Comment: You have to insert your loading overlay before the $.ajax like you al ready do. and remove it on the success block. Did you see your 《tr》 in your dom after the ajax call..?

Comment: can you show me in example?

Comment: I need to make that image show about 3 seconds, now it's showing about 0,2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to create a delay so the loading animation shows (I believe that is... mmm different, I'm going with that...)

[what you need is to set a timeout like so](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

now in your code the function could contain the ajax call:

```
$("#poll_vote").click(function(){
var answer = $("input.panswer:checked").val();
var p_id = $("#p_id").val();

$("#poll_load").html("<tr><td align='center'><img src='/images/ajax/ajax4.gif'/></td></tr>");

setTimeout(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "action=poll_vote&p_id="+p_id+"&answer="+answer+"&module="+module+"",
    dataType: 'html',
    url: "/ajax.php",
    success: function(data)
    {

       $("#poll_content").html(data);

    }
  });
}, 3000);
});
```

or be inside the success function, which I believe is better:

```
$("#poll_vote").click(function(){
var answer = $("input.panswer:checked").val();
var p_id = $("#p_id").val();

$("#poll_load").html("<tr><td align='center'><img src='/images/ajax/ajax4.gif'/></td></tr>");

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: "action=poll_vote&p_id="+p_id+"&answer="+answer+"&module="+module+"",
  dataType: 'html',
  url: "/ajax.php",
  success: function(data)
  {
       setTimeout(function(){$("#poll_content").html(data);}, 3000, data);

  }
});
});
```

I didn't test it, so check if in the second case data can be seen inside the callback function (it should I think...)

Hope it helps.

Comment: it's working, but still have a problem, that after autorefreshing, it's not showing voting result, just after refreshing with f5. code gives me an id=undefined

Comment: sorry the correct call should be: setTimeout(function(){$("#poll_content").html(data);}, 3000,data); passing data to it....